# Kendo DateTimePicker, after parsing the Date the Year is Incorrect

Tags: kendo-ui

Good Afternoon Fellow Code Monkey's

I'm new to StackOverflow, and Kendo UI programming. My problem is as follows. When trying to parse the date, and everything seems to work correctly until I get to the year portion.
here is my Javascript Code

```
$('#datepicker').kendoDatePicker({
format: 'MM dd yyyy',
parseFormats:['M/d/yy', 'MM/d/yy', 'MM/dd/yy', 'M/dd/yy', 'M/d/yyyy', 'MM/d/yyyy', 'MM/dd/yyyy','M/dd/yyyy','Mdyy','MMdyy', 'MMddyy', 'Mdyyyy', 'Mddyyyy', 'MMddyyyy', 'M-d-yy', 'MM-d-yy', 'MM-dd-yy', 'M-dd-yy', 'M-d-yyyy', 'MM-d-yyyy', 'MM-dd-yyyy', 'M-dd-yyyy']
});
```

Basically I want the user to be able to type the date into the Datepicker in any format, from 05052012 to 5/5/2012, etc and then the box formats. The above code for instance when entering "05052012" returns in the box 05 05 2020. Is there something wrong with how I have the year set up?

Thanks in advance,

SithApprentice

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out, seems sort of silly now. Apparently it has to do with the order in which I'm passing the formats with which I will be paresing. those with yy must come at the end, and those with yyyy must come at the beginning. I really wishTelerik mentioned this in their API Reference section for the date picker. From theier examples they make it seem like the order does not matter.